# On Selenium WebDriver how to get Text from Span Tag

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On Selenium Webdriver, how I can retrieve text from a span tag & print?

I need to extract the text `UPS Overnight - Free`

HTML code are as follow:

```
div id="customSelect_3" class="select_wrapper">
<div class="select_display hovered">
<span class="selectLabel clear">UPS Overnight - Free</span>
```

Using following code:

```
String kk = wd.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='customSelect_3']/div[1]/span)).getText();
System.out.println(kk);
```

But above code is returning/printing text: `1`.

Comment: Thank You all for great suggestions but unfortunately none of them are deriving expected result. Still displaying 1 as result

Comment: Is the text visible? With Java I was having this issue with a BR tag returning empty. Instead of `.getText()` I used `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` which will then return what I was looking for, including any HTML that is invisible or text that is hidden.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe the span element is hidden. If that's the case then use the innerHtml property:

By.css:

```java
String kk = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("#customSelect_3 span.selectLabel"))
              .getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

By.xpath:

```java
String kk = wd.findElement(By.xpath(
                   "//*[@id='customSelect_3']/.//span[contains(@class,'selectLabel')]"))
              .getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

> "/.//" means "look under the selected element".

Comment: Thank you, .getAttribute("innerHTML") really solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

I agree css is better. If you did want to do it via Xpath you could try:

```
    String kk = wd.findElement(By.xpath(.//*div[@id='customSelect_3']/div/span[@class='selectLabel clear'].getText()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should read -

```
String kk = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id^='customSelect'] span.selectLabel")).getText();
```

Use CSS. it's much cleaner and easier.. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to locate the element and use getText() method to extract the text.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("customSelect_3"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather use xpath and that span is the only span below your div, use my example below. I'd recommend using CSS (see sircapsalot's post).

```
String kk = wd.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='customSelect_3']//span)).getText();
```

css example:

```
String kk = wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='customSelect_3'] span[class='selectLabel clear']")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String kk = wd.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='customSelect_3']/div[1]/span));

kk.getText().toString();

System.out.println(+kk.getText().toString());
```

Comment: a little surrounding text would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way to get text from Span tags:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='customSelect_3']/.//span[contains(@class,'selectLabel clear')]").text
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP way of getting text from span tag:

```
$spanText = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//*[@id='specInformation']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span[1]"))->getText();
```