# Get Text from a Container

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
div id="flashMessage" class="error"> 
<span>Saved Section.</span>
<div id="errors" class="clearfix">
</div>
```

I would like to get the text which is contained in span, I tried all the locators.

Could someone please help me with the respective command and css or xpath locator in selenium, for the above query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Selenium WebDriver how to get Text from Span Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238272/on-selenium-webdriver-how-to-get-text-from-span-tag)

Comment: there is a problem with the HTML code: opening `<` for first div tag is missing. also it seems never closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
string spanText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#flashMessage>span")).getText();
```

I'm not sure why the same locator wouldn't work for success messages, but you can try this:

```
string spanText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#flashMessage.msg>span")).getText();
```

Comment: As long as I am getting error messages this code works fine but If I get a success message 'Saved Section' locator cannot find the element. Have any ideas about this?

Comment: @AdemDogu I'd have to see the HTML of a success message to answer that.

Comment: <div id="flashMessage" class="msg" style="opacity: 0.596775;">
<span>Section saved.</span>
</div>
This is the HTML code for the success message. For error messages it sends a list into the same flash container and makes the color red. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I figured out the problem, after getting success message it returns a unique number(12345) and also redirects to that page: url/12345. In this case any suggesting to solve this problem?

Comment: @AdemDogu From what you're describing, a success results in a short display of the success message, and a redirect to another page? If that is the case, you can test the URL to see if the action was successful. I'm of the opinion that the scenario you're describing might benefit from an entirely new question.

Comment: What really happens is first success message pops up and redirects to another url. Testing new url will add at least 3-4 sec to the test but anyways better then nothing. Thank you so much Richard.